# How to make a toggleable mat-sidenav push also a fixed header in the mat-sidenav-content

Tags: css, sass, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I'm using the mat-sidenav-container to create the desktop version of my page, but I want to make the mat-sidenav toggleable , which I've already managed to do.
The problem now is that I have a fixed header on the mat-sidenav-content, and that part is not being pushed when the mat-sidenav is displayed.

For the  mat-sidenav-content I'm using the css grid to divide this section into two parts (the fixed header and the main content)

[image]

Here's [a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ll5zo).

Do you have any idea how I can make the mat-sidenav push also the fixed header?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove these styles from *.content__header*:

```
height: 12rem;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
```

and add `position: sticky` to it. Because of the `position: fixed`, the block could not be pushed to the side by the sidebar and because of the fixed height, it overflowed when the `position: fixed` was removed. The height was especially not needed, as you already specified it in your *.content* class with this: `grid-template-rows: 12rem auto;`. Changing it to `position: sticky` makes the header still be there on scroll, but also be pushed to the side. Important is that `top: 0` is still there.

The *.content__header* class should now look like this:

```
.content__header {
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 14 I tried the following mat-sidenav-container and it works. Let me know how it goes for you.

```css
.app-sidenav-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #eee;
}

.app-sidenav-content {
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.app-sidenav {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="app-sidenav-container">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
        <mat-toolbar color="primary">
            Contacts
        </mat-toolbar>
        <mat-list role="list">
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 1</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 2</mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 3</mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
          
    </mat-sidenav>
    
    <div class="app-sidenav-content" >
        <app-toolbar></app-toolbar>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <button type="button" mat-button (click)="(sidenav.opened) ? sidenav.close() : sidenav.open()"> Open Sidenav </button>
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```